# Mysql UUID function, does it prevent duplicates?

Tags: mysql, php

lets say i use

```sql
INSERT INTO database(column1)
VALUES (uuid());
```

if i do the same again

```sql
INSERT INTO database(column1)
VALUES (uuid());
```

(lets assume the UUIDs are both the same, somehow)

will mysql throw an error for it, or just wait until a UUID is created that does not exist?

using UUIDv4 (in PHP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to consider here:

Firstly generating the values. Unless there is a fault in the generation algorithm¹ the chance of two generated UUIDs colliding like that is *astronomically* small. So much so you shouldn't need to worry even if generating many many millions of them.

There is of course nothing to stop you manually reusing a UUID like:

```
SET @id = UUID()
INSERT SomeTable (id) VALUES (@id)
INSERT SomeTable (id) VALUES (@id)
```

or

```
INSERT SomeTable (id)
SELECT id
FROM SomeTable
```

This is where the second point comes in. If you have told the database that all values in that column should be unique then yes, it will raise an error in these cases. Otherwise it is valid to allow the same UUID to be there multiple times. There are three ways that a column may be marked as unique in this way:

1. It is defined as the table's primary key
2. It has a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT defined against it
3. It has an appropriate UNIQUE INDEX defined against it (note that this does not enforce the column being exactly unique if the index is compound, i.e. it covers more than one column)

---

<sub>[1] I originally suggested v1 UUIDs and others that use a local static portion like a MAC address as having more chance of collision due to reduced randomness. This is only true if you somehow have a duplicate MAC address or there is some other flaw in the algorithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Collisions for a bit more detail.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Unless the uniqness is declared in the table you may end up with duplicate values. The risk is very low, but nothing prevents the function from generating the same uuid that have been generated before. The function has no information of what values it or someone else have generated before.